# Error 2:error: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

i am trying to run the project in android studio and it gives a full error :-

> Android resource compilation failed
>   C:\Users\mohammadfarooq\Desktop\MaterialWallpaper\app\src\main\res\layout\layout_recent_wallpaper.xml:**2:
>   error: not well-formed (invalid token).**
>   C:\Users\mohammadfarooq\Desktop\MaterialWallpaper\app\src\main\res\layout\layout_recent_wallpaper.xml:
>   error: file failed to compile.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>1<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/rootlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/latest_grid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    android:visibility="@string/admob_visibility"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_publisher_id" />
```

Comment: Remove the 1 from first line of layout XMl.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>**1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here

> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`**1**`<RelativeLayout`

### You need to remove **`1`** from your layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rootlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/latest_grid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        android:visibility="@string/admob_visibility"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_publisher_id" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: now i am having this error       Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\mohammadfarooq\Desktop\MaterialWallpaper\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1780: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.
C:\Users\mohammadfarooq\Desktop\MaterialWallpaper\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1781: error: resource android:attr/font not found.

error: failed linking references.

Comment: @noobkid where you are using `android:attr/font` in your code?

Comment: sorry i was not using anything nither attr/fontStyle nor attr/font

Comment: please help me... I am new

Comment: @noobkid can u share your `build.gradle` file with question

Comment: which one app folder or gradle scripts folder i have 2 build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 1 from first line of layout XMl.

**1**

Comment: now i am having this error Android resource linking failed C:\Users\mohammadfarooq\Desktop\MaterialWallpaper\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1780: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found. C:\Users\mohammadfarooq\Desktop\MaterialWallpaper\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1781: error: resource android:attr/font not found. error: failed linking references